# JS: Drag and Drop img disappears if dropped on another img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, drag-and-drop

I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

<div class="dropzone" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;"></div><br>
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
</div> <br>
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
<img class="draggable" style="margin: 10px;" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/11/b3/c2/11b3c29e3ea42196c9cfea5fd00ac546.png" height="100">
<img class="draggable" style="margin: 10px;" src="https://image.spreadshirtmedia.net/image-server/v1/compositions/22839312/views/1,width=300,height=300,version=1478003241/smiley-smile-men-s-t-shirt.jpg" width="100">
<script>
    $(".dropzone").on("dragover", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".dropzone").on("drop", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    });

    $(".draggable").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == null) {
            $(this).attr('id', 'draggable' + i);
        }
    });
    $(".draggable").on("dragstart", function(ev) {
        ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zpecfp0g/2/

The code works fine. If I try to move an `img` to any of the `div` boxes, it gets moved as expected and there is no issue.

The problem I'm having is, if I move one of the `img` on top of another `img`, the first one get deleted.

When moving draggable text onto other text or on the `img`, it works fine, and when moving the `img` onto the text it works fine as well. From my testing, the issue only happens when moving an `img` onto another `img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `drop` event happens on the `.dropzone`, `ev.target` will be the element that the image was dropped on. If dropped over another image, it will try to append the dropped image to the existing one instead of the dropzone div.
To fix, change
`ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`
to 
 `this.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.